# How to add another image modal (W3S-code)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this code in W3S:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img

I can't figure out how to add another image modal next to the existing image.

And I bet this is easy for people who understand javascript, unfortunately I don't and would be so happy if someone explained.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code they supplied is that the JavaScript relies on an image ID, which you can only have one of in the entire document. 
By mainly swapping out the;
    `var img = document.getElementById('myImg');`
with;
    `var imageList = document.querySelectorAll('img');`
and looping on the results you will be able to add multiple images.

I updated the code as an example with two images on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1rrLfax/) hopefully you will find that useful.

Comment: Wow! Never tried this before and I got an answer so quick! I will for sure try this, thanks a million for your time and answer!